# How can I print with Simpy which resource each customer goes to?

Tags: simulation, simpy

I have a two source simulation study. How can I print with Simpy which resource each customer goes to?

I am getting the sources as below, but how can I print which customer and which source, I am new in this field, could you help me please?

```
env = simpy.Environment()
server = simpy.Resource(env, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with simpy.Resource is its resources are generic, they have no unique id or other characteristics.  simpy.Resource simple tracks the count of resources.  If you want to track individual resources, you need to create your own resource class and use a simply.Store as your resource pool.

Here is a example

```
"""
Example of using resouces with a identity instead of
the resouces that come with simpy.Resource class

In this example, instead of using a simpy.Resource, I use
a simpy.Store.  The resouce has a id, and task time
which allows one resouce to be faster then another.

programmer: Michel R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Entity():
    """
    Simple entity with unique Id
    """
    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self):

        self.id = Entity.next_id
        Entity.next_id += 1

class MyResource():
    """
    A resouce class where each resouce has a unique ID
    and a different processing / task time
    """

    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self, task_time):

        self.id = MyResource.next_id
        MyResource.next_id += 1

        self.task_time = task_time

def the_process(env, entity, resource_pool):
    """
    A simple process where a entity grabs a resouce
    takes some time to do the process based on the 
    processing speed of the seized resouce,
    then relase the resouce
    """

    print(f'{env.now} Entity {entity.id} in queue for resouce')

    resource = yield resource_pool.get() 
        
    print(f'{env.now} Entity {entity.id} seized resouce {resource.id}')

    yield env.timeout(resource.task_time)

    resource_pool.put(resource)

    print(f'{env.now} Entity {entity.id} finished task and released resouce {resource.id}')

def generate_arrivals(env, resouce_pool):
    """
    generates a stream of entity arrivals
    """

    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(1,7))
        entity = Entity()
        env.process(the_process(env, entity, resouce_pool))

# boot up sim
env = simpy.Environment()
resource_pool = simpy.Store(env)

resource_pool.put(MyResource(8))
resource_pool.put(MyResource(10))

env.process(generate_arrivals(env, resource_pool))

env.run(200)
```